# GNU shell doing multiple things in a nested diff all at once

Tags: shell, pipe, xargs

I am trying to do a few things in a single line and this is my attempt:

```
coolc -P p good.cool | xargs -I {} sh -c "diff <(sed 's/@[0-9]+/@/g' {}) <(sed 's/@[0-9]+/@/g' good.out)"
```

1. I have a file called `good.out` and I want to run `sed` on it: `sed 's/@[0-9]+/@/g' good.out`
2. I want to run `coolc -P p good.cool` which prints result to stdout
3. I want to use the output from (2) in `sed 's/@[0-9]+/@/g' {}`
4. I want to `diff` (1) and (3)

Is it possible doing all of these without creating a new files and all in a single line?

Comment: You can't use `sh` to invoke bash-only syntax. It needs to be `xargs bash`.

Comment: And I'd strongly advise against using xargs here at all; there's no good reason to invoke a new shell per item instead of iterating over them in your existing shell

Comment: @CharlesDuffy is there a way without using `xargs` and accomplish the same with only `|`?

Comment: (also, there are serious security problems with `xargs -I TOKEN sh -c '...TOKEN...'` -- same with bash or any other shell -- because it injects your data into a position where it's parsed as syntax)

Comment: Yes, of course. Pipe to a `while read` loop. See BashFAQ #1

Comment: BTW, do you really need `diff`? If you're only trying to detect which lines are added or deleted, `comm` is much more efficient (doubly so if the inputs are presorted).

Comment: Can you provide a [mre] that's complete enough that people who've never heard of `coolc`, and don't have your `good.out`, can test their answers?

Comment: The fact that you used `sed 's/@[0-9]+/@/g' {}` tells us that `coolc` must write filenames to output: otherwise, that command would make no sense, because only a filename is meaningful in that position on a `sed` command line.

Comment: If you expect `diff` to only ever be run _once_, why in the world are you using `xargs` at all? The whole purpose of xargs is to run a command over and over based on the stdin stream. So your sample code and your numbered list of steps conflict with each other -- we need a [mre] if we're to know what your _actual_ intent is.

Comment: ...anyhow -- I could believe that my answer is wrong, but you need to explain _unambiguously_ what your program is trying to do before anything else could be written without it being pure guesswork at trying to determine intent.

Comment: (remember, when you run `sed expression filename`, the thing in the `filename` position is a **file name**, not the literal text you want sed to run the expression against)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the original code was wrong to use xargs, and you really want to run `diff` only once:

```
diff <(coolc -P p good.cool | sed 's/@[0-9]+/@/g') \
     <(sed 's/@[0-9]+/@/g' good.out)
```

Comment: Thank you. Exactly what I was looking for. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

There are certainly optimizations that could be done to this (running `sed` on the same `good.out` file over and over is not very efficient), but the shortest possible translation of your code to something that works (written assuming that there was *ever actually a good reason to use xargs*):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
while IFS= read -r filename; do
  diff <(sed 's/@[0-9]+/@/g' "$filename") \
       <(sed 's/@[0-9]+/@/g' good.out)
done < <(coolc -P p good.cool)
```

- `bash`, not `sh`, needs to be used for [process substitution](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/proc_subst) syntax to be available.
- Insofar as the purpose of `coolc -P p good.cool | xargs ...` is to run `...` once per item written into the stdout of `coolc -P p good.cool`, this is better replaced with a [BashFAQ #1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) `while read` loop.
- [BashFAQ #24](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024): *I set variables in a loop that's in a pipeline. Why do they disappear after the loop terminates? Or, why can't I pipe data to read?* -- this explains why the use of `<( )` to feed the `while read` loop instead of a pipe.

Comment: NO. I meant to compare the whole file and not just a single line with replaced `good.out`. This compares line by line. I think I didn't properly explained my question.

Comment: No, it does not compare line-by-line. Each `line` variable is a filename written by `coolc` (assuming that `coolc` writes filenames -- if it did anything else your original `xargs` code would make no sense). The `diff` command is run against a `sed`-modified version of the contents of that filename.

Comment: (err, the contents of the file thus named)

Comment: Should it be `sed 's/@[0-9]+/@/g' <<<"$line"`?

Comment: @LMC, not if the line is a filename. `xargs -I {} sh -c '... <(sed 's/@[0-9]+/@/g' {}) ...'` as shown in the question only makes any sense at all if the thing being written to xargs is a list of filenames.